# Codeigniter: Adding new items to an array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I'm creating a large array of info ready to be exported as a csv.

I'm having trouble adding additional items to the array.

I've looked at the php manual and loads of other resources, but I'm unable to get it to work?

All the work is done in my controller

```
public function payments_export()
    {
        $parents = $this->Swim_model->CRUD_read_parents();
        foreach ($parents->result() as $parentsrow)
        {
            if($parentsrow->AdultID > 1000010)
            {
            $data[] = array(
                'First Name' => $parentsrow->AdultFirstName,
                'Surname' => $parentsrow->AdultLastName,
                'Email' => $parentsrow->EmailName,
            );
```

Lots more processing to produce $owes

```
                $owes = number_format(array_sum($children) - $autodiscount, 2);
                if($owes != 0)
                {
                $data['Fees'] = $owes;
                }
            }
        }
```

So I create the array $data and store three bits of info in it - lots of processing later produces $owes (which is correct), but when I try to add it to the same row in the array, it doesn't?

The foreach loop should then go through each parent and add another row to the array containing the four items on each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $data array is multidimensional and to add to a specific part of it you would need to know the index.  Try this:

```
public function payments_export()
{
    $parents = $this->Swim_model->CRUD_read_parents();
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($parents->result() as $parentsrow)
    {
        if ($parentsrow->AdultID > 1000010)
        {
            $data[] = array(
                    'First Name' => $parentsrow->AdultFirstName,
                    'Surname' => $parentsrow->AdultLastName,
                    'Email' => $parentsrow->EmailName,
            );

            $owes = number_format(array_sum($children) - $autodiscount, 2);
            if($owes != 0)
            {
                $data[$i]['Fees'] = $owes;
            }
            $i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To expand on this approach, in general using a for loop instead of a foreach could be a better idea since we're not reading the array, but manipulating it.

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you do the loop, you redefine `$data['Fees']`. Think of it like this.

```
$data['Fees'] = 5;
echo $data['Fees']; // 5
$data['Fees'] = 3;
echo $data['Fees']; // 3
```

What you want is to add ['Fees'] as the value for the most recent element. Not tested, but something like this should get you the last element.

```
array_push($data[count($data)-1]['Fees'], $owes);
```